# How to generate unique alphanumeric content in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Say, values would be 1000-characters long.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you don't just want to use [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid)s?  They're only 32 chars long, but there are near infinite combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 64-bit integer field as backing and then convert to [base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36), putting as many leading 0's as are needed in order to pad to your target number of characters (1,000 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

`concat(md5(rand()), md5(rand()), ...)` should do the trick without much fuss.