# How to save unique alphanumeric content in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

for example 100-character long

Comment: FYI: To those voting to close - *generation* and *storing* data are **not** exactly the same

Comment: I vote for UUIDs. Although they are less than 100 characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a column in a table to be VARCHAR(100)
2. Make the column either the primary key or place a unique constraint on the column

Answer (score 0):

Mabe use UUID's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier

```
mysql> select uuid();
+--------------------------------------+
| uuid() |
+--------------------------------------+
| 3aee88e2-a981-1027-a396-84f02afe7c70 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.30 sec)
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question for someone else, maybe an hour ago:

[How to generate unique alphanumeric content in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380337/how-to-generate-unique-alphanumeric-content-in-mysql/2380357#2380357)

Comment: If I had to guess, the OP of the question you linked is the same person (with a different account) as this OP. The questions are *very* similar and both accounts were created today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the uuid generator as indicated by clyfe.

To store, the best discussion can be found at 
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,49626,49626#msg-49626

unfortunately u need to jump through a few simple hoops to get this done.